# Qt5WebKit not available in Qt 5.6

Tags: qt, cmake, qtwebkit

I'm trying to build the [Marble library](https://techbase.kde.org/Marble) which is using `CMake`. Building fails because **Qt5WebKit.cmake** is not found. It doesn't seem to be present in the 5.6 version.

I checked the `Maintenance Tool` to see if there was anything important missing but I didn't find anything.

Was it removed from the last version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had forgotten that QtWebKit [has been removed from Qt 5.6](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Removed_Modules).

It [has been replaced with Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html).

From here, you have two solutions:

- [Build Qt WebKit from source](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows)
- [Port from Qt WebKit to Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)

Comment: do you know how to install the released package here https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases?

Comment: Was looking for qt5webkit on clearlinux for teamviewer, upon seeing this answer, I've symlinked to `.so` file and that was enough